# How to check for color equality in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have the following code:

```
Item {
    width:  fos.width; height: fos.height

    Rectangle {
        id: fos
        width: 120; height: 120
        color: "red"

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                if (fos.color == "red") fos.color = "gray"
                else fos.color = "red"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to change the `Rectangle` color when the `MouseArea` is clicked. However, the code does not work. Where is my fault?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is your test:

```
fos.color == "red"
```

`"red"` is only a name or alias for `"#ff0000"`. You can see it by printing the value, i.e.:

```
//...
MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
        console.log('fos.color:', fos.color); // fos.color: #ff0000
        //...
    }
}
```

According to [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-color.html) you should use `Qt.colorEqual()` or test against `"#ff0000"` for color equality.